# What are the actual visa/entry requirements and precautions for Indians travelling to Maldives for vacation?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, covid-19, solo-travel, maldives

**Websites already checked:**

- [Maldives UK high commission](https://www.maldiveshighcommission.uk/index.php/maldives/vaccination-advice/111-visit-maldives).
- [Maldives Indian high commission](https://hci.gov.in/male/?8946?000).
- [Maldives Ministry of Tourism](https://www.tourism.gov.mv/en/page/updates_on_the_covid_19_situation_in_the_maldives).
- [Indigo Maldives website](https://www.goindigo.in/information/visa-information/maldives-mv-visa.html).

As an Indian wishing to go to Maldives on a solo budget vacation (less than Rs.80K total expense), I need help with some info:

1. Is it necessary to show a Covid19 vaccination certificate even in 2023? Do they require people to be double vaccinated and have a booster shot, or is just any one vaccination certificate enough? Is a soft-copy enough? Do they actually ask for the certificate? The ministry of tourism website says:

> Effective 5th March 2022, passengers entering into the Maldives are NO
> LONGER required to present a Negative PCR test result upon arrival if
> the individual(s) have completed the prescribed dose(s) of a Covid-19
> vaccine approved by the Maldives Food & Drug Authority or WHO
> Emergency Use Listing (EUL) and at least 14 days have passed since.
> (Booster dose(s) are not required to be eligible for this exemption).

But the info seems outdated. So if a person has got vaccinated with a dose of Covishield vaccine in 2020, is the person allowed to travel there?
2. Is the Yellow Fever vaccination necessary? AFAIK, Indians don't need to show it. I'm worried about the vaccine due to the [1 in 125000](https://www.travelclinicny.com/who-should-or-should-not-get-yellow-fever-vaccine.html) chance of [GB Syndrome](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/hcp/vis/vis-statements/yf.html).
3. Is the "confirmed hotel booking" sufficient if it is shown as an online booking? Do you carry a printout of the booking (in-case the phone is lost or damaged)?
4. There's a requirement of "Visitors are required to hold at least USD 100.- per person per day to cover their stay". How exactly do authorities check this info? Do I take a printout of my bank statement to show it? Am I supposed to have $100 worth of money in my savings account? Can it be as fixed deposits?
5. Since it is visa-on-arrival, can I simply book the hotel online (even if it's a refundable booking) and book the plane tickets online and just travel to Maldives, and the visa will simply be given to me for free on arrival? I assume the airlines would do some checks too before boarding?
6. Am I supposed to carry passport sized photos with a white background? Why is it required?

I don't want to end up in a situation where I spend so much to travel there and then get sent back just because some tiny requirement was not fulfilled. I'm asking all this because I'll be going there alone, and doing all bookings on my own instead of using some travel agent or travel website to do things for me (which would be expensive). So I need to know every single detail.

Comment: Q7-10 should be asked separately IMHO

Comment: For question 1, https://www.emirates.com/fr/english/help/covid-19/travel-requirements-by-destination/maldives says no masks, no tests, no quarantine, no vaccination (updated 5 May 2023). A traveller form is supposedly still required.

Comment: Q2: https://www.maldiveshighcommission.uk/index.php/maldives/vaccination-advice/111-visit-maldives#:~:text=However%2C%20if%20you%20are%20arriving,yellow%20fever%20to%20enter%20Maldives. says you need it if you come from a country where YF is prevalent (parts of central Africa and South America). India is not on the list.

Comment: The thing about the airline's websites is that the info may be incorrect. Indigo airline's website mentioned that yellow fever vaccination was necessary. When I wrote to them, they updated the website and removed the yellow fever vaccine requirement. I even wrote to the Maldives Ministry of Tourism, but got no response, and their website seems to have only old info. That's why I asked on this site, so that any Indian (or anyone) who has traveled there (or plans to travel in the next few months) could provide info on what actually happens after reaching Maldives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you'd just need at least 1 month validity on your passport, return flight ticket, paid hotel booking, fill out [Traveller Health Declaration](https://www.immigration.gov.mv/immigration-introduces-electronic-traveller-health-declaration/) on [Imuga](http://imuga.immigration.gov.mv/), and you're all set!

1. You don't need vaccination certificate or PCR test.
2. India is not in the [Yellow Fever endemic country list](https://www.immigration.gov.mv/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/YELLOW-FEVER-COUNTRIES-2.pdf).
3. Confirmed hotel booking should be sufficient. Can't hurt to printout in case you couldn't use your phone.
4. If you **don't** have a return flight ticket and prepaid confirmed hotel booking
   , then yes, you'll have to provide proof of funds. Cash, credit cards, electronic/printed statements, online banking, traveler's cheque — all are ways to provide proof of access to funds.
5. Yes, free visa on arrival. Airlines may check if you have the confirmed hotel booking and completed Imuga (Traveller Health Declaration) before they let you check-in.
6. Not required, but comes in handy

Do refer to the [Immigration website](https://www.immigration.gov.mv/tourist-visa/) to make sure you're meeting the requirements listed there. Safe travels!

Comment: This answer is very helpful. So it has to be a prepaid hotel booking. I thought I could just book a hotel and pay for it when I reach there. Certain websites also mention that the passport needs at least 6 months validity, but 1 month is sufficient according to the immigration website. Thanks for this.

Comment: @JohnDavid Glad to help! Yes, prepaid hotel booking is the requirement stated. You might get lucky and get away with just a booking, but best to stay out of trouble right?  Lot of countries have the 6-months passport validity rule, so it's often considered a general rule.